# Will Subscription Product Purchase Token be reissued?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am implementing In-App Subscipriton for Google and IOS

When I look at the explanation page for subscription, I have a question that I can not understand.

Will the payment token be reissued when a subscription renewal period is over and payment is made again?

When the payment is first made, we record the payment token on the backend server and are worried about whether we need to update the token afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Play subscriptions, the token that is created at purchase time remains fixed. It does not change as each successive renewal takes place. Now, if the user cancels the subscription, but *re-subscribes* before the subscription expires, I believe the token stays the same. But if they re-subscribe *after* expiration, it's basically treated as a new purchase, and comes with a new token.

Source: Months of bitter experience.

Comment: For the following case how to handle it. User A subscribed the plan 1 (play store account example abc).
- Plan 1 expired. At the time "user A logout" and "user B logged" into the same mobile
- Now resubscribed by the user on the Play Store.
- Now "user B" enters the app new token will be it but here user B not doing the subscription.

Thanks.